# How to override fprintf in the C library? How to add GCC option to toplevel CMakeLists.txt?

Tags: c, function, overriding

I know how to overwrite C-lib functions in just simple sample. But what I need is IN A REAL PROJECT which has hundreds of files that call fprintf.

In each file, there's a `"#include < stdio.h >"`, and tens or hundreds of calls of `fprintf`. I wanna make all these fprintf to do my own job. I cannot remove the `"stdio.h"` and put a `"#include < myprint.h >"`, where `myprint.h` defines the real function or macro of `fprintf` that do my own job. `"stdio.h"` has many other calls in the project. I want a simple enough solution.

Thanks!

Do I make my question clear enough?...

Update on 2014.03.08:
Salute to all women at first...

Please see my 2nd post below.

Comment: I don't think there is any other way!!, might you can still try doing `#define fprintf my_func` in a header file which suits best, then give the definition of my_func.

Comment: @Ishmeet in my_printf.h i has "#define PRINT_STDERR_FILE do{fprintf(stderr, xxx); fprinf(fp, xxx);}while(0)" where this fprintf is the C library one defined in stdio.h. I use PRINT_STDERR_FILE at some critical prints. do you mean "#define fprintf PRINT_STDERR_FILE"?

Comment: wouldn't creating header file with the your fprintf prototype and declaring it before <stdio.h> work ? as function wont be declared twice because of header guard in stdio.h. (not sure wanted to if i correct ? )

Comment: @McArthorLee you already have `#define PRINT_STDERR_FILE do{fprintf(stderr, xxx); fprinf(fp, xxx);}while(0)`, then above this line try `#define fprintf my_printf`... (not sure if it will work though, but give it try)

Comment: thx all. i'll try it this weekend. i'm busy with another ergent project... i'll give feedback ASAP.

Answer (score 4):

If you are using gcc for example, you can invoke it in the following way:

```
gcc -include myheader.h -Dfprintf=myfprintf file.c
```

And that will include `myheader.h` before every other include header in `file.c` and will redefine `fprintf` as `myfprintf`.

You can find more details [here](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Preprocessor-Options.html#Preprocessor-Options)

Comment: thx for quick answer. but my project use cmake, i'll look into CMakeFile to see where to add it.

Comment: I imagine in your makefiles the compiler is called using a make variable such as $(CFLAGS) - I don't know the syntax in cmake - and hopefully those variables are defined in a global makefile. If all that is true, it is just the case of changing CFLAGS (or some other variable) to include the switches I mentioned above.

Comment: "*any other simpler solution*" simpler then the one-liner proposed by *rfernandes*? I doubt this ... @McArthorLee

Comment: thx all. i'll try it this weekend. i'm busy with another ergent project... i'll give feedback ASAP.

Answer (score -1):

Question update overview: I added GCC option to CMAKE, but it seems not working.

***====== SOLUTION TO MY FIRST POST ======***

Hi all,

As for the question in my first post, I found a hook solution as follows:

```
#define _GNU_SOURCE
// for time() and localtime()
#include <time.h>
// for fprintf/fwrite
#include <stdio.h>
// for va_* functions
#include <stdarg.h>
// for dlsym
#include <dlfcn.h>

// compile command line: gcc -shared -Wl,--no-as-needed -ldl -fPIC -Wall hooktest.c -o hooktest.so
// how to use: LD_PRELOAD=hooktest.so ./hooktestprog, where hooktestprog includes stdio.h and calls fprintf

// a helper function
void print_time(FILE *fp, const char *format, ...)
{
    va_list args;
    va_start(args, format);
    vfprintf(fp, format, args);
    va_end(args);
}

// GCC optimizes fprintf to fwrite
// to make original program use fprintf exactly, compile the program (not this library) with -fno-builtin-fprintf
int fprintf(FILE *stream, const char *format, ...)
{
    static int (*my_fprintf)(FILE *stream, const char *format, ...) = NULL;
    if (NULL == my_fprintf)
    {
        my_fprintf = (int (*)(FILE *stream, const char *format, ...))dlsym(RTLD_NEXT, "fprintf");
    }

    va_list args;
    va_start(args, format);

    time_t tNow = time(NULL);
    struct tm *tmNow = localtime(&tNow);
    print_time(stream, "%04d/%02d/%02d %02d:%02d:%02d === ", tmNow->tm_year+1900, tmNow->tm_mon+1, tmNow->tm_mday, tmNow->tm_hour, tmNow->tm_min, tmNow->tm_sec);
    my_fprintf(stream, format, args);

    va_end(args); 
    return 0;
}

// GCC optimizes fprintf to fwrite
// to make original program use fprintf exactly, compile the program (not this library) with -fno-builtin-fprintf
/* size_t fwrite(const void *ptr, size_t size, size_t nmemb, FILE *stream)
{
    static size_t (*my_fwrite)(const void *, size_t, size_t, FILE *) = NULL;
    if (NULL == my_fwrite)
    {
        my_fwrite = (size_t (*)(const void *, size_t, size_t, FILE *))dlsym(RTLD_NEXT, "fwrite");
    }

    time_t tNow = time(NULL);
    struct tm *tmNow = localtime(&tNow);
    print_time(stream, "%04d/%02d/%02d %02d:%02d:%02d === ", tmNow->tm_year+1900, tmNow->tm_mon+1, tmNow->tm_mday, tmNow->tm_hour, tmNow->tm_min, tmNow->tm_sec);
    my_fwrite(ptr, size, nmemb, stream);

    FILE *fp = fopen("/home/idesclient/log_freerdp.log", "a");
    if (NULL != fp)
    {
        print_time(fp, "%04d/%02d/%02d %02d:%02d:%02d === ", tmNow->tm_year+1900, tmNow->tm_mon+1, tmNow->tm_mday, tmNow->tm_hour, tmNow->tm_min, tmNow->tm_sec);
        my_fwrite(ptr, size, nmemb, fp);
        fclose(fp);
    }

    return nmemb;
} */
```

I wanna override fprintf, but GCC optimizes fprintf to fwrite. You can check this by writing a sample that calls fprintf, compile it, and use the command "nm yoursample | grep @GLIBC_2.0". you can see something like "fwrite@GLIBC_2.0", and there is NO "fprintf@GLIBC_2.0".

But I cannot override fwrite because there are other fwrite calls in my project. As you can see, I commented out fwrite().

I found another solution: add "-fno-builtin-fprintf" while compiling a sample program, and now the sample works. NOTE: only the sample works, not my project works... The command line is as follows:

```
>gcc -shared -Wl,--no-as-needed -ldl -fPIC -Wall hooktest.c -o hooktest.so
>gcc -fno-builtin-fprintf sample.c -o sample # where sample.c calls fprintf
>LD_PRELOAD=./hooktest.so ./sample
```

Now I can see fprintf adds time information - fprintf is hooked.

***====== NEW QUESTION STARTS HERE ======***

By now, it seems I can add "-fno-builtin-fprintf" to my toplevel CMakeLists.txt (the project has many subdirectories, it's quite a complex project), and everythind SHOULD work. But in real practice, it does not.

I have the following lines in my toplevel CMakeLists.txt:

```
if(CMAKE_COMPILER_IS_GNUCC)
    xxxxxx (this is the original definitions in my project)
    set(CMAKE_C_FLAGS "${CMAKE_C_FLAGS} -fno-builtin-fprintf")
endif()
```

But after I compile the project, use "LD_PRELOAD=/xxx/hooktest.so /xxx/project/bin/somebinary", fprintf is not hooked.

I do another test. In my C code above, I comment fprintf and uncomment fwrite (GCC optimizes fprintf to fwrite, see expaination above), and remove the "-fno-builtin-fprintf" in the toplevel CMakeLists.txt. I can see fprintf hooked to fwrite in my code, but only fprintf(stderr, "xxx") hooked, but fprintf(stderr, "xxx %s %d xxx", somestring, someinteger) not hooked. It seems that fprintf with % and more than 2 arguments cannot be hooked.

Please help to debug this. Thanks!

Comment: Please do not post new questions in an answer. To ask a new question, use the "Ask Question" button at the top of the page.