# How to wrap a library function with custom code?

Tags: c, function, overriding

I have a library which implements `malloc`. I want to override this function with a custom malloc function that does something and then calls the malloc function of the library.

How can i redefine the symbol `malloc` without losing the function from the library?

Comment: Why can't you use different name for it?

Comment: Let's say for example that I want to compile a binary of it, and later load that binary within some other application. Then the binary would provide the symbol `malloc`, but has it's own implementation (which then "redirects" to the real malloc).

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22241757/how-to-override-fprintf-in-the-c-library-how-to-add-gcc-option-to-toplevel-cmak

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19023018/overriding-c-library-functions-calling-original

Comment: How can I eat my cake and still keep it? :)

Comment: I'm not eating the cake, I'm just pushing it aside and bake a new one. :)

Comment: I actually found a solution to this, see my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The GNU linker provides the `--wrap symbol` flag to wrap a custom function around an existing function.

As you can read here, last flag: http://ieee.uwaterloo.ca/coldfire/gcc-doc/docs/ld_3.html#SEC3

> ```
> --wrap symbol
> ```
>
> Use a wrapper function for symbol. Any undefined reference to `symbol` will be resolved to `__wrap_symbol`. Any undefined reference to `__real_symbol` will be resolved to `symbol`. This can used to provide a wrapper for a system function. The wrapper function should be called `__wrap_symbol`. If it wishes to call the system function, it should call `__real_symbol`. Here is a trivial example:
>
> ```
> void *
> __wrap_malloc (int c) {
>     printf ("malloc called with %ld\n", c);
>     return __real_malloc (c);
> }
> ```
>
> If you link other code with this file using `--wrap malloc`, then all calls to `malloc` will call the function `__wrap_malloc` instead. The call to `__real_malloc` in `__wrap_malloc` will call the real `malloc` function. You may wish to provide a __real_malloc function as well, so that links without the `--wrap` option will succeed. If you do this, you should not put the definition of `__real_malloc` in the same file as __wrap_malloc; if you do, the assembler may resolve the call before the linker has a chance to wrap it to malloc.

Answer (score 0):

it is not a good practice to create new functions with the names of library functions. If at all you want to create such a function, your new function will work fine but you can not use the library function. If you want to create your own version of printf(), you can do so but you can not use the original printf() function as you are overriding.

Answer (score 0):

If both functions have the same prototype, you can use a function pointer

```
#include <stdlib.h>

void *my_malloc(size_t len) {
    return malloc(len);
}

int main(void) {
    void *(*malloc_pointer)(size_t);

    malloc_pointer = my_malloc;
    malloc_pointer(42); // uses my_malloc;
    malloc_pointer = malloc;
    malloc_pointer(42); // uses malloc;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: That would allow me to call the original `malloc` by using ´malloc_pointer`. But I want to create a custom `malloc` and call the original `malloc` from within my wrapper - see my answer.